# Content image slighlt off center to logo

Tags: html, css

I am starting to get the swing of centering things. Although sometimes I feel like things are just a wee little off centered.

[image]

This is actually quite an obvious example. I have just created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v2s0s8aq/#&togetherjs=UD7Kxv7D0r.

HTML

```
<div class="word">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="#"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="#"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="#"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.word {
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   display:inline-block; 
}
.word img {
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 450px;
   height:450px;  
   border: 12px white solid;
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: could you provide any screenshot of what you have now and what kind of result you are expecting?

Comment: Seeming slightly of center may be caused by a scrollbar that pushes the content aside (in some browsers/OS).

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is exactly but try 'text-align: center;' on the parent div. Also here's a fiddle to show you how to streamline your css a little.. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/qex6vc0b/

Comment: Also, I recommend an account at jsfiddle and/or http://codepen.io/ they're both great tools to help you get answers to any questions you may have. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll get jsfiddle!

Comment: OK i think I got everything centered. The only problem now is when I shrink the screen the logo box doesn't center with the rest of the content. Does anyone know why? here is  my updated coding. https://jsfiddle.net/v2s0s8aq/#&togetherjs=UD7Kxv7D0r.

Comment: If you change the .word img display to 'block' (instead of inline-block) it should work! You need the display:block for margin: 0 auto to work.